# is there s possibility to get the variable name from within code in Android/Java or iPhone/objective-C for debugging

Tags: java, android, objective-c

I frequently use constants defined like:

```
private static final int myConstant_x = 1;
private static final int myConstant_y = 2;

private int anyVariable;
anyVariable = myConstant_x
```

during debugging it would be really helpful to somehow access the name of the variable for log output instead of the value.

```
Log.i (TAG,"this is debug output of anyVariable with constant name: " + ????);
```

with output:
**"this is debug output of anyVariable with constant name: myConstant_x"**

instead of

```
Log.i (TAG,"this is debug output of anyVariable with constant name: " + anyVariable);
```

with output:
**"this is debug output of anyVariable with constant name: 1"**

Is there any way?

I know one can get the method name from within code but is there a way to get the variable name too somehow?

Would be really helpful

Thanks

EDIT: updates/corrected the example code - sorry for the first misleading version

Comment: Why not use enums instead of constants? See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/enums.html for more information.

Comment: I know this question was asked 8 years before. But if anyone wants to do the same as the OP, think about do you really need to use the variable name in the logs. Because the name is just a pointer to the actual variable and it can be changed while minifying the code or some other means.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could get the fields of a class using reflection and iterate over them. You'd then have access to the name and the value.

Something like this:

```
public void logStaticFields( Class<?> clazz) throws IllegalAccessException {
  for( Field f : clazz.getDeclaredFields() ) {
    if( Modifier.isStatic( f.getModifiers() ) ) {
      boolean wasAccessible = f.isAccessible();
      f.setAccessible(true);
      Log.i (TAG, "this is debug output of static field " + f.getName() + ": " + f.get( null ) );
      f.setAccessible( wasAccessible );
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to only log constants (which normally are static final) you could check for `Modifier.isStatic( f.getModifiers() ) && Modifier.isFinal( f.getModifiers() )`.

This method also temporarily disables access checks, otherwise `get()` might throw that `IllegalAccessException`. Note that this might still not work, depending on your JVM's `SecurityManager` configuration.

Note that this only works for fields (class or instance variables) and method parameters, not for local variables within a method since theres no reflection information for those.

Comment: thanks - that looks really good - but how do I just get this ONE contant (like in my example myConstant_x) and not a list of all of them? - or did I miss something?

Comment: @user387184 well, you could get the field using `getDeclaredField(name)` but in that case, why don't you just add the name directly to the log message and skip all the hassle with reflection?

Comment: ...oh sorry, I think I made a mistake - actually I have a variable that has been assigned by a constant and I need the name of the constant when logging the variable's value instead of the value - sorry for that. But then I could use the approach you posted - just having to find the name with the value. Right? also I tried to call logStaticFields(MyClass) but I get a compiler error: Constants cannot be resolved to a variable - I though I could just pass a Class name?

Comment: @user387184 you could look for the constant with the given value but in case multiple constants have the same value that would be ambigous. And since constants are inlined you don't have information which one it actually was. As for the compiler error: you have to use `MyClass.class` as the parameter.

Comment: Thanks very much! Super I got it to work using your approach. This simplifies debugging my code quite alot!

Answer (score 1):

In Objective-C, you can define a macro:

```
#define NameAndValue(v) #v, v
```

and use it like this:

```
NSLog(@"The value of %s is %d", NameAndValue(myConstant_x));
```

Of course, if `myConstant_x` is not an `int`, you will need to use the appropriate format specifier instead of `%d`.

Comment: didn't know the #? what does it mean when I write #v ?

Comment: can't in tis case - why? would it be easier to log enum names?

Answer (score 0):

Constants are inlined by the compiler when you compile the code. At runtime (i. e. in the JAR or executable binary) they are not present anymore, but for their values. That's why what you are trying to do will not work.

For Java, you can see this when you do a search for a constant in Eclipse (using Strg-Shift-G). You get a warning telling you that this search might not work for libraries you do not have the source code for, because the names of the constants are not stored in the binary form.
Of course you might be able to work around some of these cases by using reflection and other tricks, but I am not sure this would be worth the trouble for a thing as simple as logging. Reflection is slow and generally complicated and a good source of new errors.

As for C/Objective-C I am pretty sure, no such facility exists, but I won't be held for that :)